# Go through every file in a specific directory

Tags: shell, terminal, sh

```
VTDRoot="./home"
for file in "$VTDRoot/Scenarios/"
do
   echo "filename is $file"
done
```

So I have a folder called Scenarios where I keep specific files. But when I try going through the files I only get one result which is: `filename is ./home/Scenarios`

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$VTDRoot/Scenarios/"` expands to `./home/Scenarios`, which is exactly one file.

What you want, is to use a [wildcard](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm):

```
for file in "$VTDRoot/Scenarios/"*
```

---

Using [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will help you spot those errors easily.